# "carry on" vs "proceed"?

Tags: word-choice

I would like to have a sentence to say I will study those new ideas next.

This is what I wrote:

> The following new ideas will be `carrying on`.

or

> The following new ideas will be `proceed`

I was wondering which of them sounds more formal? And, am I using `will be` correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Neither of these is idiomatic. *Ideas* cannot perform actions like *carry on* and *proceed*—it is **you** who do these things.

If you have just been talking about the ideas you are studying now, you might say that the new ideas will *follow* or *come next*. But I really think that something like your opening description is the best approach: "I will be studying these new ideas next." It's simple and clean, with no metaphors. As Mies van der Rohe said, "Less is more".

Answer (score 0):

*Proceed* sounds more formal to me (AmE), but your phrasing is very awkward.

I would lead off with the "moving forward" phrase, and follow with the ideas.

> Proceeding with ideas A and B, we see that C...

Also, "carrying on" has a connotation of something being [boring](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carrying-on), though I think BrE and AuE may feel differently.